# How can I delete some specific style in sub-item spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to add spinner on my android project. I add some style by using shape tags. Also I add an arrow but cannot delete them in sub-items. How can I do that?

Looks like this:

[spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpy8W.png)
[spinner2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z92Se.png)

**My StartingTextActivity.java**

```
public class StartingTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startingtest);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,R.layout.spinner_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
}
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_down_icon"
    />
```

**activity_startingtext.xml**

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

**edit_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <padding
        android:top="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        />

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/blue"
        android:width="1dp"
        />

    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: so, how can ı fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I add another xml file in project which called spinner_dropdown_item.xml and organized my java codes like this:

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,R.layout.spinner_item);
 **adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);**

 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then I add my arrow just in the spinner_item. Not in the spinner_dropdown_item.

I hope it will help.